# Cucumber scheduling the job to generate token

Tags: spring-boot, rest, cucumber, bdd

I want to generate the token and the token is used to run the REST API calls in Cucumber test cases. I am using Spring Boot and during `@PostConstruct` , I generate the token and used it initially.

The token is expired in 30 minutes. However, all my BDD test cases take 1 hour 10 minutes to run. In between the run, my token expired and the scenarios failed while calling REST API's.

I have an idea to use `Scheduler` to generate the token every 25 mins once before expiry and use the newly generated token. Having a question of, how to set the token once it is generated in every 25 minutes and forcing the scenarios to use the new token without any interruption in the existing run. Strongly feel someone would have faced the same situation while running BDD test cases.